# IPhone SDK MapKIt Multiple Points and Annotation

Tags: iphone, ios4, mapkit

I am new to IPhone SDK Development i am trying to make an application with MapKit i have done the first bit i want to add multiple pins and annotation to the application but i am lost here.

Following is the code how can i add more pins to this code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
 [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
 [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    MKCoordinateRegion region={{0.0,0.0,},{0.0,0.0}};
 region.center.latitude = 26.438047;
 region.center.longitude = 50.116422;
 region.span.latitudeDelta=0.01f;
 region.span.longitudeDelta=0.01f;
 [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 
 [mapView setDelegate:self]; 

 DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
 ann.title = @"Corporate Office";
 ann.subtitle =@"King Khalid Street";
 ann.coordinate=region.center;
 [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
 }

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
 MKPinAnnotationView *pinView=nil;
 if (annotation != mapView.userLocation) {
  static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
  pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
  if (pinView ==nil) pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
            initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];
  pinView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
  pinView.canShowCallout=YES;
  pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
  pinView.calloutOffset= CGPointMake(-5, 5);
  }
 else {
  [mapView.userLocation setTitle:"I am here"];
 }
 return pinView;
}
```

Comment: Same way you are adding the first pin.  What's the problem?  By the way, you should do `[ann release];` after the addAnnotation.

Comment: Hi i tried several thing [ann release]; and redo the code with different variables and tried for loop didnt worked help please?

Comment: Show the for-loop you tried (add it to the question).

Answer (score 2):

you are on the right track already, just reuse your code to make multiple points. 
for example :

```
 DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];   


 for( int i =1;i<=5;i++ ){
     region.center.latitude = 26.438047+i;
     region.center.longitude = 50.116422+i;
     ann.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"title %d",i)];
     ann.subtitle =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"subtitle %d",i)];
     ann.image = [NSString stringWithFormat@"image_%d.png",i];

     ann.coordinate=region.center;
     [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
  }
 [ann release];
```

in result, will display 5 points in different coordinate. (with same name and subtitle).

Edited: show different pin image. you have to add new field as NSString *image to DisplayMap. and add your path image inside for loop.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)amapView viewForAnnotation:(id      <MKAnnotation>) annotation
    {
 NSLog(@"pinnview before release %d",[pinView retainCount]);

if (pinView !=nil) {
    pinView =nil;
    [pinView release];
}
NSLog(@"pinnview after release %d",[pinView retainCount]);

// if it's the user location, just return nil.
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;

if(annotation != map.userLocation)
{

    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"your-pin";

    pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];

    if ( counting < [map.annotations count])
    {
        counting++;

        pinView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];


        for(DisplayMap* a in map.annotations)
        {
            if (annotation == a){
                pinView.image =
                [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
                 [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:a.image ofType:nil]];   
            }
        }
        pinView.centerOffset= CGPointMake(0,-10);
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;


    }

}

return pinView;
```

}

Comment: Hi thanks for the input i tried this way but it stops showing the pin i tried this approach updating my question

Comment: for(int i=1; i<5;i++){[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard]; [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES]; [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES]; MKCoordinateRegion region={{0.0,0.0,},{0.0,0.0}}; region.center.latitude = 26.438047+i; region.center.longitude = 50.116422+i; region.span.latitudeDelta=0.01f; region.span.longitudeDelta=0.01f; [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; [mapView setDelegate:self]; DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; ann.title = @"Corporate Office"; ann.subtitle =@"King Khalid Street"; ann.coordinate=region.center; [mapView addAnnotation:ann]; } [release ann];}

Comment: @tlikyu: You have to create a new instance for each annotation to create multiple pins (like user592514 is doing in his example).

Comment: @user592514: The code in your comment is ok overall but you probably don't see all the pins because the region span is set to 0.01 but your pins are being placed across 5.0 degrees (so increase the span to see them).  Also, move all the mapview settings to outside the loop (it's not good or necessary to change the map's region for each pin added).

Comment: ok thank you so much so if i want to you string array fro lattitude and longitude i mae an array use count and then refer the longitude and latitude and i have to increase the span right ?

Comment: Ok Guys thank you so much for your support, now i want to change the image for pin for each location in the map any tips?

Comment: simple, inside viewForAnnoation. pinView.image =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image-name.png" ofType:nil]];. you can put different images by adding new field to your 'DisplayMap' as UIImage. then assign in in viewForAnnotation. I can show you some code, if you still unclear bout this.

Comment: Thanks tilkyu i tried that and i am able to change the pin image but still unclear about how to change for different pins by adding new fields also i am using this pinView.canShowCallout=YES; on view load but popups are not called out on view load can you guide me here too thanks